# C struct getting doubly included

Tags: c, compiler-errors, header-files

I can't figure this out...

I have object.h which looks like so

```
struct basicObject {
       int x, y;
}

void objectSet (int x, int y);
```

Now I need to include object.h in my main file but I also need the objectSet function and struct in a different file called svg.c

svg.h looks like

```
#define OUTPUT_FILE "output.svg"
#include "object.h"

void saveSVG (basicObject item);
```

But my main file also includes svg.h! So I'm getting 'redifinition errors' of struct basicObject. This clearly has something to do object.h getting included twice. How can I fix this?

Comment: If you're not compiling as C++ or have edited out a typedef, in `saveSVG`, you'd need `struct basicObject`.

Answer (score 4):

You should use [include guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) if you plan on using `#include` to refer to the same header file more than once, but you only need to include it the first time.

Answer (score 2):

There are two main options. In your header file, do

```
#pragma once
```

or wrap the entire header file in:

```
#ifndef MY_SVG_H
#define MY_SVG_H

... your code ...

#endif
```

Further reading:

- [Wikipedia: Pragma once](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once)
- [Wikipedia: Include guard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard)

Comment: (do note however that `#pragma once` is non-standard)

Comment: Suggest you to make both,
#pragma once
#ifndef ..
#define ..

=> You keep advantage of fast compilation with pragma once, but portability with define.